# state-space averaging with matrices not same dimension

Tags: circuit-analysis, switch-mode-power-supply, circuit-design, power-electronics, state-space

Below are [procedures for state-space averaging:](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=iCP64kBSRoUC&pg=PA192&lpg=PA192&dq=%22state%20space%20averaging%22%20%22dimension%22&source=bl&ots=c_ePJoIVoN&sig=Mub6qcgxHXj5avugIy5PDG_Xxvg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiup9KroJDXAhVMx7wKHQ-NCuMQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=%22state%20space%20averaging%22%20%22dimension%22&f=false)

**Question**:

For some circuits, each matrix pair (A1 and A2) or (B1 and B2) doesn't have the same dimension. 
To be specific, A1 is not same dimension as A2 or B1 is not same dimension as B2. So it doesn't make sense to add these matrix together.

So how do we use state-space averaging in that case?

I think [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=849772) also talk about the problem. However, it is too complex for me to understand.

[image]

Here is a specific example for this problem. Please see the picture.

[image]

Comment: pad-out the smaller matrices with zeros.

Comment: if we add zero then for example diL/dt =0, this isn't necessary mean iL = 0 in this case but iL can be constant.

Comment: You need to give an example of the state equations. If iL and diL/dt are not present , then they are not declared as states.

Comment: I will try to give an example later but let's consider one case when assuming that during period D*T, the circuit include one capacitor C1. During (1-D)*T the circuit is not included capacitor C1. So for D*T period the matrix A1 has C1 because vC1 is state variable. However, for (1-D)*T period, the matrix doesn't include C1 as vC1 is not a state in this time now. So as you said, you add 0s to make the two matrices same dimension. This means that you assign dvC1/dt = 0 or vC1 is constant. Is that OK even when the second duration (1-D)*T, C1 not even exist in circuit.

Comment: The description in the book is surely confusing. You can only average the matrices if the state vector and input vector are the same. If these change, for example a different capacitor is chosen in each separate state-space model, then averaging the two matrices makes no sense. I would assume you must add elements for each energy storing element for both state-space models.

Comment: @anhnha How can you get different dimensions for the same circuit?!! It is impossible, you must have done a mistake here or there. You should consider the same state variables, input and outputs while formulating A1,A2, B1,B2 ... etc. Name the circuit that you are struggling with.

Comment: @Hazem: I have just added the circuit in my post. Please look at it. Thanks.

Comment: @Chu: I have just added the circuit in my post. Hope you could figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: @loudnoises: I have just added the circuit in my post. How would you add elements here? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you ignoring Vc2 in first circuit?

Comment: Since you have 3 energy storing elements in both cases, you can not ignore one in one case and consider it in the other. if it does not have impact, it should be there in x and dx/dt vectors with zeros in respective A coordinates.

Comment: @Hazem: vC2 is not a independent state variable in the first circuit because vC1 + vC2 = Vin so only vC1 or vC2 can be an independent state variable.

Comment: @Hazem: vC2 is not an independent state variable and we can't add zero as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for state 1:

$$\pmatrix{\frac{di_L}{dt}\\\frac{dv_{c1}}{dt}\\\frac{dv_{c2}}{dt}} = \pmatrix{a_{11} & a_{12} & 0\\a_{21} & a_{22} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0} \pmatrix{i_L \\ v_{c1} \\ v_{c2}}$$

As you can see from the A matrix, \$v_{c2}\$ makes no contribution to any of the equations, and also the derivative \$\frac{dv_{c2}}{dt}\$ will always be zero which makes sense as \$v_{c2}\$ is always zero.

I'm not saying that this is the correct derivation: it seems to me from the circuit that the voltage over C2 will change and therefore you need terms to account for this, but purely from the standpoint of making the matrices the same size, this is how you would accomplish that.

Comment: vC2 is not constant so it is not correct to replace these elements with 0.

Comment: Yes so you should have vC2 in your state vector in both examples. I was trying to demonstrate how to deal with a scenario in which one state is redundant in one case. You just need to rederive the correct matrices from the circuit, which is different to what your original question was.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you meant by correct matrices. If I include vC2 from the begining the result matrix is not different from the one gotten by adding zero as you did above because vC2 is dependent state variable.